# Trying to repair root mysql user permissions

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

The first step was shutting down MySQL, then reconnecting with show grants disabled:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables
--skip-networking --port=3306 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock &
```

From there I connected to MySQL with no user/password and went and fixed the grant permissions:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
```

So now my mysql.user row looks like:

```
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------+
| Host      | User  | Password                                  | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | Create_tablespace_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections | plugin | authentication_string |
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------+
| localhost | root  | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | Y          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | Y                      |          |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |        |                       |
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+------------------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------+-----------------------+
```

Then I shut down mysql and restarted without the grant tables options etc:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --port=3306 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock &
```

Then I reconnected with the root user and password and granted myself permissions to all of my local databases again:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

Still no luck.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM exp_throttle LIMIT 1;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'exp_throttle'
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I've already read and tried that. I can't even uninstall/reinstall mysql at this point as I can't get my databases out.

Comment: I gave up and fully uninstalled/reinstalled MAMP Pro from my system, and even after that the root user still can't do anything (i.e. create a new database).

Answer (score 0):

After updating query you need to flush privileges

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

To shed the light on your permissions you can run

```
SELECT user()
SELECT current_user()
```

There should be root@localhost in both cases. Then take a look at your current grants

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

IF restoring privileges in safe mode didn't help, try add another user with full permissions and connect to database with new user.

Comment: I have tried that both before and after altering the privileges. No luck.

Comment: Then you need to look at your current grants
show grants
Then run in safe mode and
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' with grant option

Comment: These are the grants I have: | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `monkey101_db`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'                                                                         
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `roll_db`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'                                                                              
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: "ON . TO" is a syntax error in MySQL 5.5.X (what I'm running). So I substituted for "ON *.* TO" assuming that's the same. Still no luck. Thanks.

Comment: That's a bug in current editor, it omitted asterisk. Look at documentation on the right syntax.
asterisk dot asterisk

Comment: Ah ok. I had already tried the asterisk dot asterisk. I re-tried in safe mode and re-flushed privileges. Root still can't give itself permissions on (or even see) the other databases in MySQL.

Comment: What if you try to add another user? For example, toor@localhost with all privileges? Will it work? I guess, you connect with the wrong user. Updated my answer.